# Network service to provide checking informations on Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, web-services, unix, daemon, snmp

I need to implement a daemon in an Unix (and also in a Linux) machine, which make a checking list for other functions in the network. This should be in two means.

1) On the client side, I need a function (Windows, preferably, but actually any language fits) which can access my server from network with something like

```
bool CheckMe (string serverName, string myStringToCheck){
     return ServiceProvidedByServer (serverName, myStringToCheck)
};
```

2) And in the Unix/Linux side, I need a service which access a text list file, and which responds `true`or `false`, if the string myStringToCheck is present or not in the list.

How can I implement this? The first attempt was to use a LDAP list, but it is not allowed (I am not supposed to create a LDAP group for doing this, but would be valid if I could create the group in Unix), so I thought about the Unix daemon.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

A friend gave me an idea. Maybe would exist an equivalent to Windows Active Directory on Unix?

Comment: snmp is a protocol meant to do exactly what you want.  You can set up one OS box to query others for a host of system data.   Check out nagios, net-snmp, what's up gold.

Comment: So should I set a snmp server on Unix? It would so read a text file and respond to queries in network asking if some string belongs to the list inside the file. I took a look in snmp documentation and found it would not be simple. Does someone would have an idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Rpc should work fine for you.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/rpc

i would recommend DBUS but im afraid its not available in windows.